# C++ GCC Optimization Speed slows down when local variable is copied to global variable

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, gcc, compiler-optimization

I have a question regarding GCC's optimization flags and how they work.

I have a very long piece of code that utilizes all local arrays and variables. At the end of the code, I copy the contents of the local array to a global array. Here is an extremely stripped down example of my code:

```
uint8_t globalArray[16]={0};
void func()
{ 
    unsigned char localArray[16]={0};
    for (int r=0; r<1000000; r++)
    {    
        **manipulate localArray with a lot of calculations**
    }
    memcpy(&globalArray,localArray,16);
}
```

Here's the approximate speed of the code in three different scenarios:

1. **Without** "-O3" optimization: 3.203s
2. **With** "-O3" optimization: 1.457s
3. **With** "-O3" optimization and **without** the final `memcpy(&globalArray,localArray,16);` statement: 0.015s

Without copying the local array into the global array, the code runs almost 100 times faster. I know that the global array is stored in the memory and the local array is stored in registers. My question is:

1. Why does just copying 16 elements of a local array to a global array cause 100 times slower execution? I have searched this forum and online and I cannot find a definite answer to this particular scenario of mine.
2. Is there any way that I can extract the contents of the local variable without the speed loss?

Thank you in advance to anyone that can help me with this problem.

Comment: In case 3, probably the compiler removed all the calculations since they cause no observable behaviour.  You could verify this by inspecting the assembly code

Comment: You could also return the localArray pointer from the function, which would also prevent the compiler optimising the entire contents of the function away. This would give a better comparison.

Comment: @Conor That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @TartanLama, yes you're right of course, maybe better pass in the GlobalArray and populate that? That way you could see the difference with and without the memcpy

Comment: @TartanLlama No, it isn't. Using the returned pointer would be UB, but merely returning it wouldn't. I'm sceptical it will disable the optimisation though.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. I have instead passed the "globalArray" to the function and it seems to have better performance. I guess that the 100 times speed improvement was too good to be true.

Comment: @hvd Yeah, I assumed that they would also try to access it, but I was imprecise. It seems that [GCC](https://godbolt.org/g/1F5IUy) still carries out the optimisation if you just return the local array, but [Clang](https://godbolt.org/g/KcCiQv) does not.

Comment: @hvd: The problem is that GCC knows you can't use the pointer as it can point to garbage, so why bother filling the local array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without the `memcpy`, your compiler will likely see that `localArray` is never read from, so it doesn't need to do any of the calculations in the loop body.

Take this code as an example:

```
uint8_t globalArray[16]={0};
void func()
{ 
    unsigned char localArray[16]={0};
    for (int r=0; r<1000000; r++)
    {
        localArray[r%16] = r;
    }
    memcpy(&globalArray,localArray,16);
}
```

Clang 3.7.1 with `-O3` outputs this assembly:

```
func():                               # @func()
# BB#0:
        xorps   %xmm0, %xmm0
        movaps  %xmm0, -24(%rsp)
        #DEBUG_VALUE: r <- 0
        xorl    %eax, %eax
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        #DEBUG_VALUE: r <- 0
        movl    %eax, %ecx
        sarl    $31, %ecx
        shrl    $28, %ecx
        leal    (%rcx,%rax), %ecx
        andl    $-16, %ecx
        movl    %eax, %edx
        subl    %ecx, %edx
        movslq  %edx, %rcx
        movb    %al, -24(%rsp,%rcx)
        leal    1(%rax), %ecx
        #DEBUG_VALUE: r <- ECX
        movl    %ecx, %edx
        sarl    $31, %edx
        shrl    $28, %edx
        leal    1(%rax,%rdx), %edx
        andl    $-16, %edx
        negl    %edx
        leal    1(%rax,%rdx), %edx
        movslq  %edx, %rdx
        movb    %cl, -24(%rsp,%rdx)
        leal    2(%rax), %ecx
        movl    %ecx, %edx
        sarl    $31, %edx
        shrl    $28, %edx
        leal    2(%rax,%rdx), %edx
        andl    $-16, %edx
        negl    %edx
        leal    2(%rax,%rdx), %edx
        movslq  %edx, %rdx
        movb    %cl, -24(%rsp,%rdx)
        leal    3(%rax), %ecx
        movl    %ecx, %edx
        sarl    $31, %edx
        shrl    $28, %edx
        leal    3(%rax,%rdx), %edx
        andl    $-16, %edx
        negl    %edx
        leal    3(%rax,%rdx), %edx
        movslq  %edx, %rdx
        movb    %cl, -24(%rsp,%rdx)
        leal    4(%rax), %ecx
        movl    %ecx, %edx
        sarl    $31, %edx
        shrl    $28, %edx
        leal    4(%rax,%rdx), %edx
        andl    $-16, %edx
        negl    %edx
        leal    4(%rax,%rdx), %edx
        movslq  %edx, %rdx
        movb    %cl, -24(%rsp,%rdx)
        addl    $5, %eax
        cmpl    $1000000, %eax          # imm = 0xF4240
        jne     .LBB0_1
# BB#2:
        movaps  -24(%rsp), %xmm0
        movaps  %xmm0, globalArray(%rip)
        retq
```

For the same code without the `memcpy`, it outputs this:

```
func():                               # @func()
# BB#0:
        #DEBUG_VALUE: r <- 0
        retq
```

Even if you know nothing about assembly, it's clear to see that the latter just does nothing.

Comment: Thank you. Answered it perfectly.